# MINIO Is it possible to set automatic deletion from bucket of the object after the retention date?

Tags: minio

I want to delete object after the retention date is end.
Can I do it with Bucket Lifecycle? If so, how?

And the second question, is it possible to automatically delete an object if there is a newer one available?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This will only work with a versioned bucket

Enable object lifecycle configuration on buckets to setup automatic deletion of objects after a `specified number of days` or a `specified date`.

Example:
Create a bucket lifecycle configuration which expires the objects under the prefix `old/` on `2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` date and the objects under `temp/` after 7 days.

Enable bucket lifecycle configuration using `mc`:

```js
{
  "Rules": [{
      "Expiration": {
        "Date": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "ID": "OldPictures",
      "Filter": {
        "Prefix": "old/"
      },
      "Status": "Enabled"
    },
    {
      "Expiration": {
        "Days": 7
      },
      "ID": "TempUploads",
      "Filter": {
        "Prefix": "temp/"
      },
      "Status": "Enabled"
    }
  ]
}
```

the same can be found in :https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-bucket-lifecycle-guide.html

##### Remove non current versions

```
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "ID": "Removing all old versions",
            "Filter": {
                "Prefix": "users-uploads/"
            },
            "NoncurrentVersionExpiration": {
                "NoncurrentDays": 365
            },
            "Status": "Enabled"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this is configuration on all bucket. And I have many object with different dates.

Comment: you can use days option instead of hardcoded date.

Comment: you can apply lifecycle rules at object level (putObject)